# Ruby on Rails - SunSpot doesn't return anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, sunspot, sunspot-rails

When I search a model, sunspot doesn't return anything:

routes.rb

```
get 'product/:q' => 'store#product'
```

store_controller.rb

```
if (!!(params[:q] =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)) == false #if no number
  @note = "hello"
  @search = Product.search do
    fulltext params[:q]
  @note2 = "hello2"
  end
@food_input = @search.results

else #if number
  @food_input = params[:q]
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
end
```

product.html.erb

```
<% if @search.present? %>
<% @food_input.each do |product| %>
<%= link_to product.name, product.barcode_number %>
<% end %>
<p>is number?: <%= !!(params[:q] =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/) %></p>
<p>param q: <%= params[:q] %></p>
<p>empty?: <%= @food_input.empty? %></p>
<p>note: <%= @note %></p>
<p>note2: <%= @note2 %></p>
```

Browser output when searching for Kat:

```
is number?: false
param q: Kat
empty?: true
note: hello
note2:
```

As you can see, no results, no @note2 variable. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `rake sunspot:reindex`?

Comment: Hahahaha thank you! Was really freaking out on that one.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment: `rake sunspot:reindex` and now you can mark question as answered ;)